# If I use GET with a Front Controller, does this mean I must use GET for all forms?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I have a front controller class.  In that class I have function to parse a url:

```
public function parseURL()
{
    if(isset($_GET['url']))
    {
        return $url = explode('/',filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'],'/'),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

}
```

This is based upon a RewriteRule (What I imported into IIS anyway):

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Does this mean all of my forms now need to use GET?

```
<form action="/controller/action" method="GET">
```

Doesn't everything go through the front controller, even my CRUD?

`/controller/action/id`, for example.

If it matters I am using IIS.  I do not have any hidden inputs for put, delete, etc.  I am not currently using AJAX.

Comment: GET just means that all relevant information is being passed in the url. You can still use query parameters (aka GET data) with other http verbs, e.g. post.

Comment: But if I start down this path, does this not mean I need to use GET in this application "forever."  Isn't POST supposed to be "better."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your forms can still use POST.  I would advise that you do not use GET when submitting form values as you will pollute your URL with form data.

You can also access your GET attributes just fine.

```
<form action="/controller/action/id" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="someText" />
    <input type="submit />
</form>
```

In PHP, you do your business as usual:

```
echo $_POST['someText']; //echos the input from the form control
echo $_GET['url']; //echos "/controller/action/id"
```

Comment: But what of my parser?  It uses GET (see above).  Not sure what you're tell me to do with POST here, as it relates to my parsing an incoming set of data.

Comment: Exactly. But PHP will still place the contents of the `action` attribute in the `$_GET` array, while your form input will go in the `$_POST` array.  The HTTP method will still register as having occurred via `POST`, but that isn't going to stop PHP from placing POST/GET data in their proper place.  Give it a try, you'll see it in action. :)